# How to write double condition for list comprehensions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

I have a list of strings. I want to remove those strings that have '\x1b' and '1' in them. my list is called `lst`. I tried this:

```
[i for i in lst if j not in ['\x1b', '1'] for j in i]
```

But it does not work. It says

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment.

How to do it right?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani no because it works when there are two strings in condition. but if there are a lot of them , i don't want to write so many and's